# Checkboxes to ranked list

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, code-review

So, my aim is to produce a user interface with checkboxes not only returning `True`/`False`, but also the order in which they were selected. The final goal is an intuitive or comprehensive user interface (.cdf compatible) in which several parameters could be added/removed.

The expected behaviour is a ranked list of controls. If one unmarks control b, (which was initially at rank 2) then control c (previously rank 3) has to be set to rank 2. And a renewed selection of b, would set it at rank 3. That's the principle.

[image: mockup]

I actually managed to produce the desired result... but through an INSANELY COMPLICATED and LONG code!!! Please help me to get that in a few lines! :)

```
DynamicModule[{a, b, c, a1, b1, c1},

 Panel@Row[{Legended[
     Panel@Column@{Dynamic@
         Button[Control[{{a, True, "a"}, {True, False}}],
          {
           a = If[a, False, True],

           If[Not@a, {If[b1 == 3, b1 = 2, 
              If[And[b1 == 2, c1 =!= 1], b1 = 1]], 
             If[c1 == 3, c1 = 2, If[And[c1 == 2, b1 =!= 1], c1 = 1]]}],
           a1 = If[Not@a, 0,
             If[And[b, c], 3,
              If[Nor[b, c], 1,
               2]]]
           },
          Appearance -> "Frameless"],

        Dynamic@Button[Control[{{b, True, "b"}, {True, False}}],
          {
           b = If[b, False, True],

           If[Not@b, {If[a1 == 3, a1 = 2, 
              If[And[a1 == 2, c1 =!= 1], a1 = 1]], 
             If[c1 == 3, c1 = 2, If[And[c1 == 2, a1 =!= 1], c1 = 1]]}],
           b1 = If[Not@b, 0,
             If[And[a, c], 3,
              If[Nor[a, c], 1,
               2]]]
           },
          Appearance -> "Frameless"],

        Dynamic@Button[Control[{{c, True, "c"}, {True, False}}],
          {
           c = If[c, False, True],

           If[Not@c, {If[a1 == 3, a1 = 2, 
              If[And[a1 == 2, b1 =!= 1], a1 = 1]], 
             If[b1 == 3, b1 = 2, If[And[b1 == 2, a1 =!= 1], b1 = 1]]}],

           c1 = If[Not@c, 0,
             If[And[b, a], 3,
              If[Nor[b, a], 1,
               2]]]
           },
          Appearance -> "Frameless"]}, Placed["Controls", Above]],

    Spacer[25],

    Legended[Panel[Dynamic /@ {a1, b1, c1}], Placed["Ranks", Above]]}],

 Initialization :> {{a1, b1, c1} = {1, 2, 3}}]
```

For sure, `Slot` or `SlotSequence` has to be integrated, but I failed in it.

Yes, I guess that wrapping a checkbox in a button isn't that clean...

I do not need more that 3 parameters, but why not find a generalised solution for more? :-D

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
DynamicModule[{pos = Range[3]}, 
              Panel[Row[{Column[{"Controls", 
                                 CheckboxBar[Dynamic[pos],
                                             {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, 
                                             Appearance -> "Vertical"]}], 
                         Column[{"Ranks", 
                                 Dynamic[Pane[ReplacePart[{0, 0, 0}, 
                                         Thread[pos ->
                                                Range[Length[pos]]]]]]}]}]]]
```

Comment: Excellent! Very efficient, thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
DynamicModule[{pos = Range[3]}, Panel @ Grid @ {{"Controls", "Ranks"},
    {CheckboxBar[Dynamic[pos], {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, Appearance -> "Vertical"], 
     Dynamic @ Normal @ SparseArray[MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, pos], 3]}}]
```

Alternatively, using the second argument of `Dynamic` to update ranks,

```
DynamicModule[{pos = Range[3], ranks = Range[3]},
 Panel @ Grid @ {{"Controls", "Ranks"},
  {CheckboxBar[Dynamic[pos, 
      (pos = #; ranks = Normal@SparseArray[MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, #], 3]) &], 
     {1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"}, Appearance -> "Vertical"], Dynamic @ ranks}}]
```

[image]